# "Standard" pairs and group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, terminology, group-actions

In Aschbacher's paper about automorphism groups of symmetric block designs, there is mention of "standard $(G,\pi)$ pairs" and "standard permutation groups":

> If $G$ is a permutation group on a set $\Omega$ and $\pi$ is a set of primes, the pair $(G, \pi)$ is said to be *standard* if, for all $p \in \pi$ and $g \in G$ with $|g| = p$, we have that
> $G^{F(g)}$ is a $\pi^{\prime}$-group, where, $G^{F(g)}$ is the group induced by $G$ acting faithfully on the fixed points of $g$, and being a $\pi^{\prime}$ group  means that the only primes dividing $|G^{F(g)}|$ are in $\pi^{\prime}$ (complement of $\pi$).

This mostly seems to be used as a tool to show that a group action in "standard":

> $G$ is defined to be a *standard* permutation group if every non-trivial element of $G$ has the same set of fixed points. We remark that if $G$ is standard then every non-trivial orbit of $G$ has length $|G|$.

This is equivalent to $G$ acting semiregularly on $\Omega$ after the fixed points are removed; but it is a good tool for investigating the possible actions of a given group on a set (such as determining the possible automorphism groups  of a combinatorial design with certain parameters, along with their cycle structure).

This terminology does not seem to be very common (or rather it is incredibly too common - a search for "permutation group standard pair" leads to many many hits with various meanings); is there a more standard (ha)/modern term for these properties of a group action? And/or a reference that can explain more about this?

*Aschbacher, Michael*, [**On collineation groups of symmetric block designs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(71)90054-9), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. A 11, 272-281 (1971). [ZBL0223.05006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0223.05006).

Comment: For the second one, isn't that equivalent to being free/semiregular (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions) after one removes the fixed points? I don't think I've ever seen the first one.

Comment: @verret Yes, it is equivalent to being semiregular after removing fixed points. The first seems to be a very effective tool for giving sufficient conditions to ensure we have this "essentially semiregular" action (or show other interesting properties of a group). But I have also been struggling for quite a while to find any other mention of this.